# Fingerprint reader not working

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I downloaded Ubuntu today and the fingerprint reader doesn't seem to be working.
The error message is:
"Failed to claim fingerprint device Synaptics Sensor: Device 06cb:00df is already open."
I have no idea on what to do.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lsusb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/lsusb.8.html) to verify that you have a finger print reader connected to the USB bus. For example, on a Thinkpad T420 the fingerprint reader appears as `Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor` in the output below.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If the fingerprint reader shows up in the `lsusb` output, check to see if it is supported by [fprint](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/). They have a list of [supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html). Then name you found using `lsusb` ought to match the devices listed at https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html.

If it all checks out, install the `fprintd` package. You can do this using the commands `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y fprintd`.

This will install the command line utility [`fprintd-enroll`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/fprintd-enroll.1.html). This utility is used to enroll fingerprints. The `fprintd` package installs `fprintd-list`, `fprintd-verify`, and `fprintd-delete` which you can use to manage your enrolled fingerprints.

If you require a graphical user interface, you can use [fingerprint gui](https://launchpad.net/%7Efingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) which is not included in the Ubuntu packages and is not supported on Ubuntu 20.04 and later.

Or you may have to update the firmware per the suggestions of the answers to [Synaptics 6cb:00df fingerprint sensor not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307127/synaptics-6cb00df-fingerprint-sensor-not-working).